# Most simple and direct way to check asp.net session expired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, session-variables

Is code below more than enough to check if session is expired?

```
if(Session["yyy"] == null)
{
    //Do zzz
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A session is a [HttpSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx)  object. When the old session object expires, you get a new one. You could use the following:

```
if(Session.IsNewSession) // true if the session was created with the current request;
{
// do shizzle
}
```

please note that 'IsNewSession' will remain true if the session object is empty.

Concerning your question, your check will only prove if the session contains the value "yyy" or not. It will not show if it's a new session. While that it might prove the session is new for your code at this time, other people reading it will most likely not understand straight away what the check is for.